# Enable multiple GCP APIs on multiple Projects with foreach (not count)

Tags: loops, google-cloud-platform, foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'd like to enable multiple GCP APIs on multiple projects. The way I am currently doing it is:

```
resource "google_project_service" "customer_projects" {                          
   count   = length(var.my_projects) * length(var.apis_customer_projects)
   project = google_project.customer_projects[var.my_projects[floor(count.index / length(var.apis_customer_projects))]].project_id
   service = var.apis_customer_projects[count.index % length(var.apis_customer_projects)]                              
}
```

`var.my_projects` and `var.apis_customer_projects` both contain lists.

But as described in this excellent [article](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9), `count` has some drawbacks and I would rather like to use `foreach`.

There used to be a `google_project_services` (note the plural), but seems to be deprecated in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I believe the best option would be using the setproduct() function to loop through the two list variables within the same resource.

Here is an example from the Terraform docs:

```
locals {
  # setproduct works with sets and lists, but our variables are both maps
  # so we'll need to convert them first.
  networks = [
    for key, network in var.networks : {
      key        = key
      cidr_block = network.cidr_block
    }
  ]
  subnets = [
    for key, subnet in var.subnets : {
      key    = key
      number = subnet.number
    }
  ]

  network_subnets = [
    # in pair, element zero is a network and element one is a subnet,
    # in all unique combinations.
    for pair in setproduct(local.networks, local.subnets) : {
      network_key = pair[0].key
      subnet_key  = pair[1].key
      network_id  = aws_vpc.example[pair[0].key].id

      # The cidr_block is derived from the corresponding network. See the
      # cidrsubnet function for more information on how this calculation works.
      cidr_block = cidrsubnet(pair[0].cidr_block, 4, pair[1].number)
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  # local.network_subnets is a list, so we must now project it into a map
  # where each key is unique. We'll combine the network and subnet keys to
  # produce a single unique key per instance.
  for_each = {
    for subnet in local.network_subnets : "${subnet.network_key}.${subnet.subnet_key}" => subnet
  }

  vpc_id            = each.value.network_id
  availability_zone = each.value.subnet_key
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr_block
}
```

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setproduct.html#finding-combinations-for-for_each